# ESLint - object-curly-newline

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

Is there a way to allow for `{}` (an empty object) while keeping the rest as is?

```
    "object-curly-newline": [
      "error",
      {
        "ObjectExpression": "always",
        "ObjectPattern": { "multiline": true },
        "ImportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 4 },
        "ExportDeclaration": "never"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An empty object `{}` is `ObjectExpression`, so it always breaks line with your rule by specifying `always`. You can keep empty object without breaking line by configuring `minProperties` `> 1`:

```json
{
  "ObjectExpression": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 1 },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just disabled that rule for a specific section of code:

```
...
/* eslint-disable object-curly-newline */
... [code for which rule will not be applied] ...
/* eslint-enable object-curly-newline */
...
```